# Why are <for i in obj:> and <for i in iter(obj):> equivalent?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, iterable

The following example is given by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/functional.html#iterators):

> In the statement `for X in Y`, Y must be an iterator or some object for which `iter()` can create an iterator. These two statements are equivalent:
>
> ```
> for i in iter(obj):
>     print(i)
>
> for i in obj:
>     print(i)
> ```

According to this same [source](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators),

> Behind the scenes, the for statement calls `iter()` on the container object. The function returns an iterator object that defines the method `__next__()` which accesses elements in the container one at a time. When there are no more elements, `__next__()` raises a `StopIteration` exception which tells the for loop to terminate.

Considering both cases, when Y is an iterator or some object for which iter() can create an iterator,

- if Y is an iterable (has an `iter()` method), the *for* statement calls this method and returns an iterator whose `next()` method is used to iterate through each element of Y. I assume this is the second example above.
- if Y is an iterator (has both an `iter()` and `next()` method), the *for* statement still calls  the `iter()` method, but because it's an iterator, it returns it`self`, and the `next()` method is called as usual. I assume this is the first example above.

My question being, is my line of reasoning correct? I don't mind if you point out any misuse of a definition.

Comment: Yes, you have the logic right. A call to `iter(iter(x))` works the same as a call to `iter(x)`. That's essentially what happens in your two example loops, with the `for` statement doing the outer call to `iter`.

Comment: Technically, they *aren't* equivalent if you have an iterator that doesn't implement `__iter__` by returning itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter.

> `iterator.__iter__()`
>
> Return the iterator object itself. This is
> required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the
> for and in statements. This method corresponds to the tp_iter slot of
> the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.